# How to search value in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, regex

Using Google Sheets, I am trying to two compare two columns on Google Sheets, like the one below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK1wd.png]

Basically, I want to compare column A and B, basically, if a cell in column A is inside a cell in column B (the number is inside the URL), I want to return the matching column B value in column C. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), REGEXMATCH(B1:B&"", A1:A), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), IF(REGEXMATCH(B1:B&"", A1:A), B1:B), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B1:B&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A)), B1:B), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! Right now it only returns if the columns are aligned, is there to make the code work if for example the content of B1 was in B2 instead?

Comment: you mean like B column is offset by 1 row or B column contains mixed stuff that is not aligned anyhow with column A ?

Comment: Yes that is the exact situation, B column contains mixed stuff that is not aligned anyhow with column A

Comment: @user222813 answer updated